# how to darw the image faster in canvas

Tags: javascript, python

I am capturing mobile snapshot(android) through monkeyrunner and with the help of some python script(i.e. for socket connection),i made it to display in an html page.but there is some time delay between the image i saw on my browser and that one on the android device.how can i synchronise these things so that the mobile screen snapshot should be visible at the sametime on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for the image to get from your phone to your server to your desktop client. There's nothing you can do to change that.

The best you can hope to do is to benchmark your entire application, figure out where are your bottlenecks, and hope it's not the network connection itself.